# Angular 12 Translation not worknig

Tags: angular, translate, ngx-translate, angular12

Everything work fine in local -> 4200 `ng s`
But
When I run

```
ng build --configuration production --build-optimizer   or 

`npm run build`

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/lib/translate.pipe' in 'xyz/component/search-filter'
```

On local machine everything run good but on server or prod giving this error.

Issue with ngx-translate translate pipe.

Code:

```ts
TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: (MultiTranslateHttpLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Can you please add your main module? If you are lazy loading those translations (I have no idea why would you do that but still), be sure to import the TranslateModule.

Comment: it's working fine on angular 11. I was upgrading to angular 12 then it's start giving problem.

Answer (score 0):

So i Face the same problem and nothing works i tried all the ways it's was issue of angular/core12.0.0. I waste 3 days in it. It was working fine in angular 11 but no one angular 12. So Create custom pipe. :) Now it's working

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from "@ngx-translate/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'myTranslate',
  pure: false
})

export class MyTranslate extends TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any {
    return super.transform(value, args)
  }
}
```

Html

```
{{ myvalue | myTranslate }
```